# How to close an access made by unknown proccess to a file through WPF, C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, file, file-access

I'm trying to access a file with my WPF project and I get an exception saying it couldn't access the file because another process is using it.
I don't see any reason because the only process which used it was syncronized and it should close the file after it used it. I tried the "client.Dispose();" below, but it didn't help.
Any advice may be a help! Thanks.

I'm trying to access "currentQr" file in local url. Here's my code:

```
private void BtnScanQR(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            currentQr= System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog.FileName).Replace(@"\\", @"\");
            if (!bL.IsQRExist(currentQr))
            {
               /////// some code
            }
        }            
    }
```

It calls "bL.IsQRExist(currentQr)"  which calls "dal" :

```
public bool IsQRExist(string currentQr)
    {
        return Dal.IsQRExist(currentQr);
    }
```

Here's my Dal.IsQRExist function, Which calls directly to "DecodeQR" function:

```
public bool IsQRExist(string currentQr)
    {
        Product p = Tools.ConvertQRToProduct(currentQr);
        if (GetProductID(p) == -1)
            return false;
        return true; }
```

And in "Tools.DecodeQR" there's the Actual access to the file:

```
public static string DecodeQR(string downloadUrl) //'unzip' qrCode from url and interperts its meaning
    {
        string imageUrl = downloadUrl;
        // Install-Package ZXing.Net -Version 0.16.5
        var client = new WebClient();
        var stream = client.OpenRead(imageUrl);
        if (stream == null) return "";
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
        IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
        var result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
        client.Dispose();
        return result.Text;
        
    }
```

After this only access to the file, I'm trying to access the file again in another proccess but it says that another proccess (must be this one i descibed here, cause when i cancled this it didn't throw the exception).
So how can I make sure the file isn't being accessed anymore after this code above?
And I also thinks maybe is there a way to close all accesses to a file, whether they were made in this code or any other code.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of using `Dispose()` use a `using` block. WebClient,Stream and Bitmap all need to be disposed. By forgetting to dispose `Stream` you keep the file opened and locked

Answer (score 2):

Since Bitmap is an `IDisposable`, you have to make sure that you properly dispose of it after usage, which is usually done by creating it in a `using` statement.

In addition, when you load a Bitmap from a local file, you would not have to deal with Streams at all.

This should be sufficient:

```
public static string DecodeQR(string imageFilePath) 
{
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(imageFilePath))
    {
        return new BarcodeReader().Decode(bitmap).Text;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the file handle, that isn't closed, is held by the variable `stream` which receives the file opened by WebClient.OpenRead. You will need to dispose the stream resource as well.
With a `using` block it's disposed automatically when the block is exited - where `using` guarantees to invoke Dispose even in case of exceptions thrown inside the using block. Which is quite good, when you want to open that same file later again.

Also I think you don't need a WebClient if you deal with a local file. Just opening that file as a FileStream seems more straight forward.

```
using System.IO;
...

    public static string DecodeQR(string localImageFile) 
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(localImageFile, 
                FileMode.Open, FileMode.Read))
        {
            if (stream == null) return "";
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);       
            // Install-Package ZXing.Net -Version 0.16.5
            var reader = new BarcodeReader();
            var result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
            return result.Text;
         }        
    }
```

Comment: Wow that really helped!   I realized that I also use this function for non-local files, but that's alright cause I can play with it (with "if"s, dividing to different functions, etc). Thanks a lot, G-d bless you

Comment: You're welcome :) Of course it's your own choice whether or not to keep the webclient based code, just to have a flexible handler for all kinds of  Uris - or if you prefer  to devide it into two functions. I would personally not use resources I don't need... but you're free to decide as a programmer.